# Xamarin Forms: Adding multiple TapGestures in a ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have built a Shared Header which is shared across my content pages. This Shared header is a ContentView, with a few labels. I've added TapGestures for 4 of these lables. Now when I run the app, only the first 3 labels I've declared will fire the tapgesture event. I've checked this by rearranging the labels in Xaml.
Platforms:iOS
Xamarin Forms Version : 2.2.0.45

Here's the Xaml

```
<StackLayout>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="ss" Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="For :" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblUser" Text="Chris Shepard" TextColor="#3170A6" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Active Quotes:" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"></Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblQuotes" Text="1" TextColor="#3170A6" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
      </StackLayout>          
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Active Con Notes :" TextColor="Black" ></Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblConNotes" Text="2" TextColor="#3170A6" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Balance:" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">        
        </Label>
        <Label x:Name="lblPayment" Text="$ 234.56" TextColor="#3170A6" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" >
        </Label>
      </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
  </Grid>
  <StackLayout>
    <Button/>
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black"/>
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

And here is the backend code where i've attached tapgestures for the labels

```
 public partial class SharedHeader : ContentView
{
    public SharedHeader()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           

        var tapGestureRecogniserQuote = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecogniserQuote.Tapped += TapGestureRecogniserQuote_Tapped;
        lblQuotes.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecogniserQuote);

        var tapGestureRecogniserConNote = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecogniserConNote.Tapped += TapGestureRecogniserConNote_Tapped;
        lblConNotes.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecogniserConNote);

        var tapGestureRecogniserAccount = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecogniserAccount.Tapped += TapGestureRecogniserAccount_Tapped;
        lblUser.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecogniserAccount);

        var tapGestureRecogniserPayment = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecogniserPayment.Tapped += TapGestureRecogniserPayBal_Tapped;
        lblPayment.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecogniserPayment);

    }

    private void TapGestureRecogniserPayBal_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetCurrentPage() != "Payment")
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Payment());
    }

    private void TapGestureRecogniserAccount_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetCurrentPage() != "Account")
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Account());
    }

    private void TapGestureRecogniserConNote_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(GetCurrentPage() != "ConNotes")
            Navigation.PushAsync(new ConNotes());
    }

    private void TapGestureRecogniserQuote_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetCurrentPage() != "Quotes")
            Navigation.PushAsync(new Quotes());
    }

    public string GetCurrentPage()
    {
        var page = Navigation.NavigationStack.Last();
        return page.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Or does Xamarin not support more than 3 tapGestures in one form?

Comment: Which `Xamarin.Forms` version? Which Platform(s)?

Comment: It is iOS and the unconstrained button, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<Button/>` is the element that is causing you the issue, I changed the background to red to see it in the previewer:

```
<Button BackgroundColor="Red"/>
```

On Android it is fine:

[image]

But on iOS, being unconstrained, it is covering your last `Grid.Row` and thus the tap is going to the button and not the label:

[image]

You will need to constrained the height of it or the layout that contains it, maybe giving the two top level `StackLayout` a starred height (i.e. `*9` and `*1`)

Comment: You're a star. Thank you :)